# Rails 5 relacion muchos a muchos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql

Estoy teniendo un problema en la vista a la hora de presentar los datos.

Tengo 3 modelos usuarios, sponsors y mascotas
Resulta que sponsors en un tabla join entre usuarios y mascotas que son n a n, mi problema esta a la hora de mostrar todos los sponsors de la mascota en la vista ya que lo logro pero de una manera errada a la hora de msotrar los datos. Espero me puedan indicar como solucionarlo. Gracias.

Index.html.erb

```
<h1>Sponsors#index</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="histories">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Mascota</th>
        <th>Padrinos</th>
        <th>Apadrinar</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <% @pets.each do |pet| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= pet.name %></td>
                <td>
                    <% @users.each do |user| %>
                        <% @sponsors.each do |sponsor| %>
                            <% if user.id == sponsor.user_id and pet.id == sponsor.pet_id %>
                                <%= user.email%>
                            <% else %>
                                <p>No Tengo Padinos =-( </p>
                            <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>
                </td>
                <td><button>Apadrinar</button></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Mi controlador tiene los tres modelos que estoy enviando a la vista.

```
def index
    @sponsors = Sponsor.all
    @users = User.all
    @pets = Pet.all
end
```

La salida que ahora me muestra la adjunto en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me pregunto también si hay una mejor manera de realizar la consulta, para mostrar los respectivo datos.

Otra cosa es como haria para ya no poder dar sponsor a las mascotas que ya le he dado sponsor??

Comment: ahi yo noto que estas mandando invocar los datos de manera individual de cada modelo, aquí la idea para lograrlo es por ejemplo muestres el `JOIN` que dices usar, pues yo en ningún momento veo que lo declares

Comment: El detalle está en que planeo hacer un link de cada mascota y sponsor a un detalle de cada uno.

Comment: para hacer lo que quieres ocupas JOIN entre la tabla pivote y las tablas intermedias para que por medio de la clave foránea recuperes los valores, invocando a cada modelo por separado simplemente no lo vas a conseguir, pues ahi lo que haces es traer los datos individuales de cada modelo

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que tu modelo pet tiene un `has_many :sponsors` y sponsor tiene un `belongs_to :user`, tu vista debería ser de la siguiente manera:

```
    <% @pets.each do |pet| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= pet.name %></td>
            <td>
                <% if pet.sponsors.any? %>
                  <% pet.sponsors.each do |sponsor| %>
                    <%= sponsor.user_email %>
                  <% end %>
                <% else %>
                    <p>No Tengo Padinos =-( </p>
                <% end %>
            </td>
            <td><button>Apadrinar</button></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Ese `sponsor.user_email` es una delegación y la consigues con:

```
class Sponsor < ApplicationRecord
  delegate :email, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

Ahh y en tu controlador solo necesitas `@pets`. Algo que también puedes hacer para no generar n+1 consultas, es usar `includes`:

```
def index
  @pets = Pet.includes(:sponsors)
end
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, Haciendo tu indicaciones y añadiendo el has_many sponsors en el modelo, logré lo deseado.

Comment: @AdrianRama me alegro. Si te fue de utilidad, recuerda que puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos